# How do I get user prompt string from serial port object by navigator.serial.requestPort() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I get user prompt string from serial port object by navigator.serial.requestPort() in JavaScript?

[image: User prompt string]

Comment: I don't think you can. https://github.com/WICG/serial/issues/128#issuecomment-1561717691

Comment: I don't know if there's a way, but what about using the [Web USB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebUSB_API)?  I wonder if there's a way to get the [USBDevice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USBDevice) object from the [SerialPort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SerialPort) object?  I presume the browser knows behind the scenes which USB device is associated with the SerialPort to produce that message.